# How can C read chinese from console and file

Tags: c

I'm using ubuntu 12.04
I want to know how can I read Chinese using C

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8");
  scanf("%s", st1);
  for (b = 0; b < max_w;b++)
  {
    printf("%d ", st1[b]);
    if (st1[b] == 0)
        break;
  }
```

For this code, when I input English, it outputs fine, but if I enter Chinese like"的"，it outputs

```
Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): 的
target char seq :
-25 -102 -124 0
```

I'm wondering why there is negative values in the array.
Further, I found that the bytes of a "的" in file read using fscanf is different from reading from the console.

Comment: Short answer: to read chinese in the console, you need to use a UTF library, e.g.: `libconv`.

Comment: Why? It´s perfectly fine that way. @cloudygoose: What´s the problem? The output is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`UTF-8`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encodes characters with a variable number of bytes. This is why you see three bytes for the 的 sign.

At [graphemica - 的](http://graphemica.com/%E7%9A%84), you can see that 的 has the value `U+7684` which translates to `E7` `9A` `84` when you encode it in UTF-8.

You print every byte separately as an integer value. A `char` type might be signed and when it is converted to an integer, you can get negative numbers too. In your case this is

- -25 = E7
- -102 = 9A
- -124 = 84

You can print the bytes as hex values with `%x` or as an unsigned integer `%u`, then you will see positive numbers only.

You can also change your print statement to

```
printf("%d ", (unsigned char) st1[b]);
```

which will interpret the bytes as unsigned values and show your output as

```
231 154 132 0
```

Comment: Even if the `char` type is implemented as `signed char`, all characters on the machine will have essentially positive values. How can converting it into an `int` get negative values?

Comment: You can interpret the value E7 as a positive value (i.e. `unsigned char`), in which case it is 231. But when you interpret it as a signed negative value (i.e. when you use `signed char`), it will be printed as -25.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need (and in fact it's harmful) to hard-code a specific locale name. What characters you can read are independent of the locale's language (used for messages), and any locale with UTF-8 encoding should work fine.

The easiest (but ugly once you try to go too far with it) way to make this work is to use the wide character stdio functions (e.g. `getwc`) instead of the byte-oriented ones. Otherwise you can read bytes then process them with `mbrtowc`.